# Find highest $m$ such that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^m 9(n+1)10^n\le10^i$ for very large $i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Consider a sum
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^m 9(n+1)10^n$$
>   and a big power of 10, like $$p=10^{100000}$$
>   What is the highest $m$ that this sum will be not greater than $p$?

In fact i'm also interested in other powers of $10$. Is there some tool to help me with this? 
I know i can use computer for low powers of ten, but with such huge power it's not really possible.

I noticed that this sum is similiar to generating function for sequence $a_n = \langle 9 (n+1) \rangle$ and is equal to $$9\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n = \frac{9}{(1-x)^2}$$ 
I also tried to take $log_{10}$ on both sides, but i just can't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to show that, for every $x\ne1$,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^m(n+1)x^n=\frac{(m+1)x^{m+2}-(m+2)x^{m+1}+1}{(x-1)^2},
$$
hence, using this for $x=10$, one sees that the sums you are interested in are
$$
S_m=9\sum_{n=0}^m(n+1){10}^n=(m+\tfrac89){10}^{m+1}+\tfrac19.
$$
To solve
$$
S_m=10^{10^k},
$$
this suggests that one should look for $m$ such that
$$
(m+\tfrac89){10}^{m+1}\approx10^{10^k},
$$
that is, to choose $m\approx m(k)$, where
$$
m(k)=10^k-k-1.
$$
Finally, one can check directly that
$$
S_{m(k)}\lt10^{10^k}\lt S_{m(k)+1},
$$
hence the largest value of $m$ such that $S_m\leqslant10^{10^k}$ is $m(k)$.

Comment: I think it's nice solution, but i have question, why $m(k)$ is equal to $10^k-k-1$?

Comment: ?? Because we define it as such. And I have a question myself: how is the accepted answer answering your query "to know what is the highest m that this sum will be not greater than p"?

Comment: From first answer i got equation $$9S = 9x10^x - 10^x-1$$ for $x=m+1$ and i just automated it to have real answer. 
And i know that your answer is more precise and easier to calculate on paper, but i just didn't understand it ( sorry >:( ) fully

Comment: "Automated it to have real answer" Meaning? But why accept not "real" answers?

Comment: I meant i used computer to calculate this $m$, 
i know that the $S_m$ form are the same, but i didn't understand your way of coming to this form. 
And after that i didn't understand why $m(k) = 10^k - k - 1$ (why not $m(k) = 2*10^k - k - 1$ for example?) I meant i just didn't understand _how_ to come to this, but i will surely change "accepted" mark to your post only if i could understand this bounding :-) Thanks for your posting @Did

Comment: If $m=2\,10^k-k-1$ then $m+1+\log(m+8/9)\geqslant2\cdot10^k$, hence $2\,10^k-k-1$ is irrelevant. For every $m$, let $A(m)=m+1+\log(m+8/9)$. Then, if $m=m(k)$ then $A(m)\lt10^k$, and, if $m=m(k)+1$ then $A(m)\gt10^k$. Ergo?

Comment: Thanks, now its much more clear :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $\displaystyle S=9\sum_{n=0}^m(n+1)10^n=9\left[1+2\cdot10+3\cdot10^2+m\cdot10^{m-1}+(m+1)10^m\right]$

$\displaystyle\implies 10S=9\left[10+2\cdot10^2+3\cdot10^3+m\cdot10^{m}+(m+1)10^{m+1}\right]$

So, $\displaystyle10S-S=9(m+1)10^{m+1}-9\left[1+(2-1)10+(3-2)10^2+\cdots\{m+1-m\}10^m\right]$

$\displaystyle\implies9S=9(m+1)10^{m+1}-9\left(\underbrace{1+10+10^2+\cdots+10^m}\right)$

The terms under the brace is a finite Geomtric Series

**Reference** : [Arithmetico-geometric sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Derivation)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but i don't really know how to continue from there (i just don't see it)

Comment: @Chris, please find the edited version

Comment: I think it works great now... I think i understood the trick. Thanks:-)

Comment: @Chris, My pleasure. Nice to hear that last statement