# Sequences and Series ( Power Series ) question.

Tags: sequences-and-series, problem-solving

$(a)$ Starting with the geometric series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$, find the sum of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}\;, \vert x\vert<1$.

$(b)$ Find the sum of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^n\;, \vert x\vert<1$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^n}$.

---

Here's the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6d11.jpg) of the question. I know that the sum from $0$ to $\infty$ of part $A$ is the same as the sum to $\infty$ from $1$ if you decrease the power by $1$. So I'm guessing the series will converge, but I don't know how to find the sum ( because $x$ can be both $+ve$ and $-ve$ ( I assumed)) .

For part $A$ I got the sum as $1+x+x^2+x^3$ and so on.
So the next bit will be $1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\dots +(\infty+1)x^{\infty}$.

My questions is am I doing it right because it seems way too easy. And if not, then what should I do?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732424/is-it-possible-to-bound-this-sum

Comment: Hint: Can you rewrite $\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)^2$ into a power series?

Comment: Hint 2: For the second part of (b), compare $n\frac{1}{2^n}$ first to $nx^n$ and then to $nx^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a closed formula (not written as an infinite sum) for the sum of a geometric series. Find out what that is. Now differentiate series and its sum formula.
For part (b) you are just playing with your series from part (a).

Comment: Thank you, didn't notice the derivative